# hexagon nnlib : output tensor prep fail -9

Tags: qualcomm, hexagon-dsp

With [Hexagon DSP SDK 3.4.3](https://developer.qualcomm.com/software/hexagon-dsp-sdk/tools), I'm following the Tensorflow/Hexagon-NN example at `examples/hexagon_nn/tutorials/007-tensorflow-to-hexagon-nn` and using the Hexagon NN lib at `libs/hexagon_nn/2.6`.

I've converted my own TensorFlow net into iv3.c and built `graph_app_q` (with `V=hexagon_ReleaseG_toolv83_v66`).

I'm seeing a surprising runtime failure:

```
output tensor prep fail -9:  HIGH:0x5E:107:log.c
recalc strategy for v66 failed:  HIGH:0x5E:107:log.c
execute() failed on node id=1004a err=-1:  HIGH:0x5E:107:log.c
fail in execute_new():  HIGH:0x5E:107:log.c
```

The referenced node id corresponds to this line in the generated iv3.c:

```
APPEND_NODE("net_0/Relu_3/eightbit",0x1004a,OP_QuantizedRelu_8,NN_PAD_NA,inputs_for_1004a,3,outputs_for_1004a,3);
```

I'm not sure what error code "-9" means.  How can I go about diagnosing this?  Are there any docs on the error codes?

Answer (score 0):

https://source.codeaurora.org/quic/hexagon_nn/nnlib/tree/hexagon/ops/src/op_supernode_new.c?id=79e35e9b4463b8fd0f1f67acbfab1470c8e21278#n4355

shows the error message you saw after a call to `tensor_out_prepare_padded_d32`.

That func's implementation is in https://source.codeaurora.org/quic/hexagon_nn/nnlib/tree/hexagon/include/nn_graph_types.h?id=79e35e9b4463b8fd0f1f67acbfab1470c8e21278#n501 where I see this code:

```
if (dst->max_size < size) return -9;
```

The error indicates that your graph exceeds the maximum allowed size.